# Next.js detect incremental rebuild vs initial build?

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to detect a Next.js incremental build vs the initial build?

The use case is that if an API call fails in the incremental build, I'd like to throw an error thus preventing static incremental build.

But if the API call fails during the initial static build I'd rather handle that gracefully and not render just the API portion of the page. I don't want to throw an error which would kill the build or otherwise prevent the page from rendering.